# Происхождение слова "немой"

Tags: этимология

Искал происхождение слова немой. Приведенные в словарях значения не отражают, на мой взгляд, особенностей этого недуга. Может роськое (талышское) нам - тихий?

Comment: «Может роськое (талышское) нам - тихий?» Mado. ==== Как это перевести с вашего талышского? Чтобы задать вопрос, разве достаточно поставить знак вопроса?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос о «роськом (талышском)» языке.

Comment: Язык роси -язык изначального русского. Вы же не закрываете вопросы, где ссылаются на праславянский, немецкий, греческий и т.п.

Comment: С нашего талышского нам - тихий. А немой скорее тихий, чем заика.

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Потому, что вопрос — не формат, и ответ будет соответственно не в формате. Править этот вопрос «при живом авторе» никто не будет, думаю.

Answer (score 4):

А Вы происхождение по значению ищите? Этак вы всю этимологию на талышский орган переведете.

Какие версии вас не устраивают? Хоть одну приведите - будем разговаривать. А пока со своим вульгарным подходом не очень смотритесь.

Вот Фасмер

> Диссимилировано из *měmъ «заикающийся», ср. латышск. mḕms «немой»,
>   męmulis «заика», memeris — то же, а также нем. mummeln, англ. mumblе
>   «заикаться, лепетать», шв. mimrа «шевелить губами».

И никакой талышской конспирологии.

*Кстати, если еще один раз напишите что-то подобное вашей конструкции "талышский(роський)" получите полноценный минус. Синонимичность этих этнохоронимов наука всерьез не рассматривает. Это очень далекие языки, талышский - иранская группа, да еще отдельная её реликтовая ветвь. А *руським* называют западнорусский, язык Великого княжества Литовского, предок современного белорусского. Кончайте уже людям голову морочить.*